# Volatile equivalent for non primitive objects c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, blocking

I think i'm missing something big here.

What i'm trying to do:

I have an object, which is known to multiple threads, which may read or manipulate it. Now i want the object accesses to block, when one thread calls obj.setProperty(T type) i want every other thread to have to wait until the property is set. How to i do this? I know that there is volatile for primitive types, but how does this translate to non primitive types.

Comment: This sounds very fishy.  Use the constructor to get the property initialized so no waiting is required.  Or use a ManualResetEventSlim that you Set() in the property setter and WaitOne() in, say, the getter.

Answer (score 3):

Use the lock statement in the property getter and setter.

Also, *you don't understand what volatile does*.  Volatile is to *prevent* blocking, not to *cause* blocking.